# AWS application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

We're trying to implement an application load balancer with different applications seperated by rules within a listener but we cannot seem to get it working properly. We're using the following set-up:
Applications/Domains:

- test1.example.com
- test2.example.com

Both of these applications are installed on different servers, when configured the load balancer with one of them then it works just fine. But now we're trying to set it up in such a way that we can hit both url's with one load balancer. The rules we've tried are the following:

```
IF
Host is test1.example.com
THEN
Forward to
test1target: 1 (100%)
2

IF
Path is/login
THEN
Forward to
test1target: 1 (100%)
3
IF
Path isportal/*
THEN
Forward to
test2target: 1 (100%)
Group-level stickiness: Off

HTTPS 443: default action
IF
Requests otherwise not routed
THEN
Return fixed response 503 (more...)
```

`Test1.example.com` has a login path and test1.example has a `portal/*` path. But neither the path config or the host: config seem to be working, it's jumping straight to the default rule and shows the custom 503 error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see in [access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) ? for these requests

Comment: Hi, the access logs were not enabled unfortunately. I just enabled it, will provide the logs as soon as i've got them. But weirdly enough it seems to work right now but i just won't believe that the configuration as mentioned in my previous post is correct.